# OS X | Impossible to empty my trash

Tags: macos, secure-erase, trash

There are four folders in my trash which are resisting any kind of deletion. So far I´ve tried multiple ways but im still stuck. 
I already searched for the same problem on superuser but so far no solution worked out for me.

At first I tried to delete the files within the directorys and then the folders themselves. The ~/.Trash/ file I want to empty/delete is the one on the external hard drive, the startup volume is fine.

```
rm -rf ~/.Trash/*
```

Doesn´t solve the problem.

At first I tried to delete all normal and hidden files within the directory with:

```
sudo rm -Rf directory/*
sudo rm -Rf directory ./*
```

Then delete the directory/folder itself with the same command above results in "Directory not empty". How can that happen when deleting all files recursively ?

I checked if there is any files left with ls -la but except "dot files" there is nothing left. Read-Write-Execute is enabled on any folder for  everyone.

There is no process accessing any file on my external volume...

```
lsof | grep "/Volumes/MyVolume"
```

I can´t tell how the files happend to be at this undeletable state. The last solution I know is to format the harddrive but I wan´t to avoid that because there must be a smarter way.

Comment: try restarting, it's possible it's just a glitch.

Comment: Are the directories on the startup volume, or on external volumes? ~/.Trash/ only holds deleted items from the startup volume. If they're on other volumes, they'll be in /path/to/volume/.Trashes/youruserID (something like /Volumes/ExtVol/.Trashes/501). Also, if it's an external volume, what format is it in (e.g. Mac OS Extended, FAT, NTFS, etc)?

Comment: @Sickest Restarting didn´t do anything.

Comment: @GordonDavisson The directories are on an external volume. Yes i agree, I forgot to mention that I am trying to delete the ~/.Trash/ file or content of the external volume. The used file system is ExFat.